# Epic cannot be closed if Story is 'In Progress'

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I need to find a way to restrict the EPIC from showing the Close transition if the stories in the Epic are in Open or In progress state.
I only have the script runner plugin.
The solution here: http://www.adaptavist.com/w/jira-genius-ensuring-that-epics-are-only-closed-when-stories-are-complete/
Doesn't work as it involves JMWE as well.

Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you see that you need JMWE?

If you have your scripted condition, then all you have to do is:

> Place the script as a condition on the transition(s) to Done for your workflow that is used by Epics and you will no longer experience Epics being closed before all Stories are complete.

(quoted from the link you provided)